# Oracle: connections closed by firewall

Tags: oracle, firewall

I have a server with Windows Server 2012 and Oracle 11g installed.
There is a problem with the connections on Oracle: the connections are lost when idle for about 10 minutes.

I did several tests and check many sites to find the problem, and I found the obvious: the problem is the firewall.

If the firewall is off, this problem do not happen. But the firewall in this case can't be off.
The following rules is the set of firewall for Oracle here:

- Oracle_home\bin\oracle.exe - Oracle Database executable
- Oracle_home\bin\tnslsnr.exe - Oracle Listener

Did I left behind something important? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your listener.ora file?

Comment: This is a server configuration issue. It would be better suited to ServerFault.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable dead client detection on the database server. This makes the rdbms server check every X minutes for the health of the client. This causes some network traffic and keeps the firewall from closing seemingly idle ports.
Set sqlnet.expire_time to less than your 10 minutes.
See [SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF209)